# Mongodb position operator only first matched workaround

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a user object with a list of notifications

```
{
 "notifications": {
 "0": {
   "id": "1",
   "isRead": false,
   "user": {
     "id": ObjectId("4f7999c5e4b0f2e6b8490e08"),
     "firstName": "X",
     "lastName": "Y",
     "profilePictureUrl": "URL1" 
  } 
},
 "1": {
   "id": "2",
   "user": {
     "id": ObjectId("4f7999c5e4b0f2e6b8490e08"),
     "firstName": "X",
     "lastName": "Y",
     "profilePictureUrl": "URL1" 
     } 
    } 
  },
}
```

When a user changes his profile pic I want to update all corresponding notifications. I'm trying to do something like this in morphia, but it seems to update only the first entry.

```
 Query<UserEntity> query = ds.createQuery(UserEntity.class).filter("notifications.user.id",
                userProperties.id).field("notifications.user.profilePictureUrl").notEqual(userProperties.profilePictureUrl);
        UpdateOperations<UserEntity> op = ds.createUpdateOperations(UserEntity.class).disableValidation()
                .set("notifications.$.user.profilePictureUrl", userProperties.profilePictureUrl);
        results = update(query, op);
```

Is there any workaround for this? I'll be doing this in a background job so a costlier solution will work as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in using $ operator. Currently the $ operator only applies to the first matched item in the query.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

You should update a whole list (fetch, modify and save).

Comment: Yuck, that seems to be the case. morphia returns [UpdateResults] (http://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/browse/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/query/UpdateResults.java?r=1796) which has a method getUpdatedCount(). Even if I run this query in a loop till getUpdatedCount is 0 it doesn't - seems like mongodb is caching the previous operation!

Comment: The other option is to review your data model. You can use a mapping instead of the list: user id -> {first_name: ..., last_name ...}

Answer (score 0):

You should set multi=True for update. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29

Comment: I'm using morphia where the update command results in having multi=true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine the positional operator with $elemMatch operator to match multiple fields and multiple documents in the sub-array.

[Check this example](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5276?focusedCommentId=98560&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-98560) from a MongoDB bug report with a similar case.